prove that the function $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{{x^2}}$ is continuous on the interval $(2, \infty)$ using epsilon delta definitions
Let $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{{x^2}}$ and I want to prove that $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ in the interval $(2, \infty).$
I started by defining $\delta$ as $\min(1, \text{  })$ and then I tried to simplify $|f(c)-f(x)|.$
However, when I try to simplify $|f(c)-f(x)|$, I got $|x-c|+|\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{c^2}|.$
The challenge is to reduce this expression so that we can use $ |x-c|< \delta$ to prove that the quantity is smaller than $ \epsilon$ and I have no idea how to do that. So presumably,
I asked chat GPT and it said $ \delta$ $\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|c|+1)})$
I have no idea how it arrived at that.(at least whether it's right or wrong as I also couldn't find a way to use it)

The $|1/x^2-1/c^2|$ term is the problem here, but we can write it as $|x^2 - c^2|/(x^2c^2)$, or assuming $x > 0$,$$|x-c| \cdot \frac{x + c}{x^2c^2} = |x-c| \cdot\frac{1}{xc}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{c}\right).$$
The $\frac{1}{xc}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$ term is now the problem. But, given your $c > 2$, and if you accept $\delta \le 1$, then $x > 1$. This term will then have an upper bound of $\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2}\left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{3}{4}$. You should then be able to parlay this into a $\delta$ value of $\min{1, 4\varepsilon/5}$.

Why would you ask ChatGPT?

Let $c\in(2,\infty)$, and observe that
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x^2}-c-\frac{1}{c^2}\right\rvert
&\leq\lvert x-c\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\right\rvert \\
&=\lvert x-c\rvert+\frac{\lvert c^2-x^2\rvert}{c^2x^2} \\
&=\lvert x-c\rvert+\lvert x-c\rvert\frac{\lvert c+x\rvert}{c^2x^2}.
\end{align*}
As you can see now, if we can just bound the term in the second factor by some constant, then it's easy to finish. As this term only becomes a problem at $0$, let us force $x$ away from $0$. One way to do this is to make $\delta\leq1$, so that $\lvert x-c\rvert<1$ which we can expand to
$$c-1<x<c+1.$$
As $c-1>0$, the left inequality then gives us that
$$\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{c-1}.$$
We also have that
$$\lvert c+x\rvert=\lvert x-c+2c\rvert\leq\lvert x-c\rvert+2c\leq1+2c$$
in this case. Consequently we get
$$\frac{\lvert c+x\rvert}{c^2x^2}\leq\frac{1+2c}{c^2(c-1)^2}.$$
Now the right hand side here is just some constant, so we are allowed to have $\delta$ depending on it. Combining this with out initial observation we get that
$$\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x^2}-c-\frac{1}{c^2}\right\rvert\leq\lvert x-c\rvert\left(1+\frac{1+2c}{c^2(c-1)^2}\right).$$
Recall that the above inequality holds when $\lvert x-c\lvert<1$, so we must take $\delta\leq1$. Now let $\varepsilon>0$ and choose
$$\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\frac{1+2c}{c^2(c-1)^2}}\right\}.$$
Then, when $\lvert x-c\rvert<\delta$, we have (using the inequalities we showed above) that
$$\left\lvert x+\frac{1}{x^2}-c-\frac{1}{c^2}\right\rvert\leq\lvert x-c\rvert\left(1+\frac{1+2c}{c^2(c-1)^2}\right)<\varepsilon\frac{1+\frac{1+2c}{c^2(c-1)^2}}{1+\frac{1+2c}{c^2(c-1)^2}}=\varepsilon.$$
This proves that $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous at $c$.

can you explain this line please |c+x|=|x−c+3c|≤|x−c|+c≤1+c. specially this part  |c+x|=|x−c+3c|

@NicholasGray whoops, that's a typo on my part, let me fix it

@NicholasGray I've fixed it now, if you still have any questions let me know!

There are certainly already tons of proofs of this continuity on this site. You are not answering the specific question of this post "$\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|c|+1)})$ ... at least whether it's right or wrong as I also couldn't find a way to use it".

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Beginning with your bound
$$
(*)\,\left|f(c)-f(x)\right|\leq \left|x-c\right|+\left|\tfrac{1}{x^2}-\tfrac{1}{c^2}\right|.
$$
When $|x-c|<1$ the second term is bounded by
$$ (**)\, \left|\tfrac{1}{x^2}-\tfrac{1}{c^2}\right|
=\tfrac{1}{x^2c^2}\left|x+c\right|\left|x-c\right|
\leq \tfrac{1}{16}(2c+1)\left|x-c\right|.
$$
The inequality is justified by: since $x,c>2$ we have $x^2c^2>16$ and since $|x-c|<1$ then $|x+c|=|x-c+2c|\leq|x-c|+2c<1+2c.$
Combining (*) and (**) we have
$$
\left|f(c)-f(x)\right|\leq\left(1+\tfrac{2c+1}{16}\right)|x-c|=\tfrac{2c+17}{16}|x-c|.
$$
when $|x-c|<1.$
Thus any $\delta>0$ smaller than the smaller of $1$ and $\tfrac{16\epsilon}{2c+17}$ works.

There are certainly already tons of proofs of this continuity on this site. You are not answering the specific question of this post "$\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|c|+1)})$ ... at least whether it's right or wrong as I also couldn't find a way to use it".
